# convert array to object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
["recordList", "userList", "lastChanged"]
```

And I want something like this:

```
lastChangedValue = "231231443234";        

var object = {};

object = {
   recordList: {
       userList: {
         lastChanged: lastChangedValue 
      }
   }
}
```

How I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the nesting consistent?

Comment: So you want each array item to be an object containing the keys beneath it as keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through property names and create one nested level of new object in each iteration:

```
var props = ["recordList", "userList", "lastChanged"];
var lastChangedValue = "231231443234";

var obj = {}
var nested = obj;
props.forEach(function(o, i) {
    nested[o] = i === props.length - 1 ? lastChangedValue : {};
    nested = nested[o];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var array = ["recordList", "userList", "lastChanged"];


var value = "231231443234";        

function arrayToObject(array, object, value) {
  var ref = object;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length-1; ++i) {
    if (!ref[array[i]]) {
        ref[array[i]] = {};
    }
    ref = ref[array[i]]
  }
  ref[array[array.length-1]] = value;
  return object;
}
alert(JSON.stringify(arrayToObject(array, {}, value)));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a bunch of ways to do it, one way is with reduce

```
var keys = ["recordList", "userList", "lastChanged"];
var temp = keys.slice().reverse(),
    lastChangedValue = "231231443234";  
var result = temp.reduce( function (obj, val, ind, arr) {
  if (ind===0) {
    obj[val] = lastChangedValue;
    return obj;
  } else {
    var x = {};
    x[val] = obj;
    return x;
  }
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that reduce was introduced in IE10 and is not supported in IE9 or below.

Answer (score 1):

Solving with recursion

```js
var fields = ["recordList", "userList", "lastChanged"];
lastChangedValue = "231231443234";
var object = {};

(function addFields(o, i, v) {
    if (i == fields.length - 1) {
        o[fields[i]] = v;
        return;
    }
    o[fields[i]] = {};
    addFields(o[fields[i]], ++i, v)
})(object, 0, lastChangedValue);


alert(JSON.stringify(object));
```